# Cocoa: How to remove invalid character from a string to create a directory

Tags: cocoa

I am new to mac os x and cocoa. I have a NSString and want to ensure that characters in it are not invalid, so that when I create a folder name with NSString it should be created and not fail because if invalid characters. or Is there a library function in cocoa to help this situation?

Comment: Create a folder, and check for an error with NSFileManager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only characters disallowed in filenames on unixy-systems are `'/'` and `'\0'`.  Macs usually have HFS+ filesystems, so I'd stay away from `':'`, too.

There are plenty of other characters that are perfectly allowable but will make you wail and cry and gnash your teeth, so whitelisting a set of "reasonable" characters might be a better way to go.

Comment: While technically supported, I would stay away from Unicode & `\0`, too. (`\0`'s are actually allowed on HFS+).

Comment: In HFS+, the `\0` will work, yeah (and so will the `/`), but if you ever have to deal with them on the command line you won't be happy.